# Newbie xpath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I try to get the xpath query to the file that contains following rows:

```
<div id="pPrice">
<b>Preis</b>
<br/>
<div class="price" style="margin-top:2px">
    <nobr>
        <span class="price_info">Jetzt 48% sparen!</span>
        <br/>
        <span class="price_info">
            Statt 
            <strike>30,60 €</strike>
            <strong> nur</strong>
        </span>
        <strong>
            <span class="productSpecialPrice">15,90 €</span>
        </strong>
    </nobr>
</div>
```

When I want to get the 'crossed' price (value is 30,60), I use following, and it works fine:

```
.//*[@id='pPrice']/div[1]/nobr/span[2]/strike
```

Now I want to get the `productSpecialPrice` (value is 15,90 €) and I tried this one:

```
.//*[@id='pPrice']/div[1]/nobr/strong/span
```

But it doesn't work. How should I edit this?

Thanks!

UPD: Now everything works fine, but in this case:

```
<div id="pPrice">
<b>Preis</b>
<br/>
<div class="price" style="margin-top:2px">
<nobr>
<span class="price_info">Jetzt 33% sparen!</span>
<br/>
<span class="price_info">
Statt 
<strike>41,70 €</strike>
<strong> nur</strong>
</span>
<strong>
<span class="productSpecialPrice">27,90 €</span>
</strong>
</nobr>
</div>
<div class="priceinfo">
inkl. gesetzl. MwSt zzgl. 
<a class="priceinfolink" href="javascript:openShipping();">Versandkosten</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="pAvailability">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
</div>
<div id="pPrice">
<b>Preis für 2. Wahl Spiel</b>
<small>
<a href="JavaScript:var win=open('/zweitewahl.html', '', 'scrollbars=no,location=0,left=300, top = 100,toolbar=0,status=0,resize=0,width=400,height=310')">
</small>
<br/>
<div class="price" style="margin-top:2px">
<nobr>
<nobr>36,00 €</nobr>
</div>
<div class="priceinfo">
inkl. gesetzl. MwSt zzgl. 
<a class="priceinfolink" href="javascript:openShipping();">Versandkosten</a>
</div>
```

The query return two values: '27,9 €' and '36 €'. How do I specify in the query that I need the '27,9 €' value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use simply following:

```
.//div[@id='pPrice'][b[text()="Preis"]]//span[@class="productSpecialPrice"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Reopened the question as I got 2 values returned by the query

Comment: Are you sure that `.//div[@id='pPrice']//span[@class="productSpecialPrice"]` returns `<nobr>36,00 €</nobr>` also? On provided `HTML` there is only one element with class name `productSpecialPrice`, so it's impossible to match something else

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've edited the question (UPD2) to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot!